# How does BJT act as a switch and as an inverted switch?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

These were the graphs shown for the functioning of BJT as a switch . I understand it intuitively but
 I don't know how to actually explain these graphs.

[image]

[image]

Could some one, in the form of equations please explain how this works?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I should have realized that I should have added my work. This is what I had done so far.

For inverted switch:

V<sub>BB</sub> = I<sub>B</sub>R<sub>B</sub> and β=I<sub>C</sub>/I<sub>B</sub>. 
If I<sub>B</sub> is 0, I<sub>C</sub> is 0, so output voltage is maximum, i.e, V<sub>CC</sub>. Also, I<sub>C</sub> increases with I<sub>B</sub> until it reaches a maximum, and V<sub>CE</sub> becomes V<sub>CE(sat)</sub>.

It's the case where output is taken at the emitter that I don't fully understand.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please see that this cannot be an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is basic information that existing texts on BJTs will explain if great detail. I recommend that you search the internet for 'BJT fundamentals' or 'BJT basics'. Voting to close for those reasons but, again, a warm welcome to the site and hope to help on future visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both schematics, you are supplying an input signal voltage at two levels: a more negative voltage, where the base current is effectively zero and the BJT is turned OFF; and a more positive voltage where the base current is supplying usefully high levels of recombination current to the BJT so that it is effectively turned ON.

The assumption in both cases is that the base current is high enough that the BJT will be "saturated" (\$V_\text{CE}=V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$, which is a small value) when taken in combination with the rest of the circuit.

Let's look at the two cases:

1. \$V_\text{BB}\$ is **low**, BJT is **off**, \$V_\text{BE}\approx 0\:\text{V}\$ and \$I_\text{C}= I_\text{E}=0\:\text{A}\$.
2. \$V_\text{BB}\$ is **high**, BJT is **on**, \$V_\text{BE}\approx 700\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{E}+V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$

The first schematic is wired so that \$V_\text{E}=0\:\text{V}\$. In case #1, \$I_\text{C}=0\:\text{A}\$. So \$I_\text{C}\cdot R_\text{C}=0\:\text{V}\$. So \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{CC}\$. So in case #1, \$V_\text{C}\$ is **high** when \$V_\text{BB}\$ is **low**. Case #2 has \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{E}+V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$, but recall that \$V_\text{E}=0\:\text{V}\$. So \$V_\text{C}=V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$, which for all intents and purposes is **low**. So in case #2, \$V_\text{C}\$ is **low** when \$V_\text{BB}\$ is **high**. *The first schematic inverts the input.*

The second schematic is wired so that \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{CC}\$. In case #1, \$I_\text{E}=0\:\text{A}\$. So \$I_\text{E}\cdot R_\text{E}=0\:\text{V}\$. So \$V_\text{E}=0\:\text{V}\$. So in case #1, \$V_\text{E}\$ is **low** when \$V_\text{BB}\$ is **low**. Case #2 has \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{E}+V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$, but recall that \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{CC}\$. So \$V_\text{E}=V_\text{CC}-V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$, which appears **high**. So in case #2, \$V_\text{E}\$ is **high** when \$V_\text{BB}\$ is **high**. *The second schematic follows (does not invert) the input.*